# Is it between or among?

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, academic-writing

My questions:

1. I am not sure which is correct in the following context, **among** or **between**?.
2. Is it correct to use `;` in this paragraph?. I do not want to use comma since it was used too many times.

> In Nepal, there is a shortage of technology and funding to research deeply on adaptation to the new scenarios resulted from the interaction **between** climate, society, and water resources **;** this is why natural catastrophes as that of 1989 continue to occur.

Comment: It is an inter-relation that is defined, hence _between_ is appropriate. Also the usage of semi-colon looks correct, since it is joining two independent clauses.

Comment: Why make a rod for your own back? Just start a new sentence at *This is why...*, as I'm sure nearly everyone else would anyway. It's an arbitrary stylistic choice whether to use ***between*** or ***among*** (or indeed, ***across*** and probably other prepositions) in your context, nothing to do with "grammar".

Comment: @pepo I had edited the question by removing the period (full-stop) after the question mark. It is not correct in English to use a full-stop after a question mark.